# Cassandra cluster many small nodes vs fewer large nodes

Tags: amazon-ec2, cassandra

I'm wondering what will be the differences between a Cassandra cluster with a few large, powerful nodes, and a cluster with many small nodes. For example, if I choose to run Cassandra on AWS EC2, what will be the difference if I choose one m4.4xlarge node, or two m4.2xlarge nodes, or 4 m4.xlarge, or 8 m4.large? They should have the same compute power, according to https://aws.amazon.com/ec2/pricing/. But will they have different performance in reality for Cassandra? Assume we always set replication factor as 1 so the comparison is fair.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I am going to answer this question out of experience. When you are launching Cassandra it requires at least 8 GB for the heap. Therefore I recommend you run on at least 8 GB of RAM, if not more.

Having more nodes obviously means that you have more redundancy, but sometimes the additional resources will be wasted if the nodes do not have similar machine types. For example, if you have 10 nodes with 100 GB of disk, then any node with more than 200 GB of disk will like go to waste. It also means that these nodes will have to communicate more with each therefore increasing the bandwidth required. For AWS, the better VM you get the better the networking.

DataStax recommends use of minimum 16 GB of RAM for Cassandra only in production and between 32-64 GB for recommended specs.

After trying both models I can tell you that the sweet spot is at 8 threads/cores, 32 GB of RAM and 1 TB of SSD.

If you can have a **minimum** of three such nodes then I think you're fine. If it's a question on whether you should get one powerful node or three less powerful for the same money, always go for the more nodes.

Comment: it's probably worth mentioning that adding a node to a 3-node cluster will destroy performance until the new node is integrated. honestly, any cluster under 10 nodes is going to have growing pains if you ever want to expand